# PYTHON: Error in recognising numpy module

Tags: python, numpy

I am using *Python 3.4.0*. I am going to assume that the `numpy` module should work, as this is one of the newer versions of python. However, anything I do with `numpy` will result in a syntax error. Forexample this code here:

```
    import numpy
    list1=[1,3,2,6,9]
    list2=numpy.mean(list1)
    print(list2)
```

And then I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/yichen/Desktop/python/numpy test.py", line 1, in <module>
        import numpy
    ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Is this just a problem with my computer or what?

Comment: Probably the numpy module is not installed on your system.

Comment: How should I install it then?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `numpy` is not installed on your system. Assuming that you have the `pip` script installed with your python, you can perform following command to install it:

```
pip install numpy
```

or

```
pip3.4 install numpy
```

Or, depending on your distribution, it might come as a package named like `python-numpy` with your package manager.

Comment: In general, I'd suggest trying your package manager first over pip.  It avoids the compilation step and for numpy, thats extensive.

Comment: Yes, it is also managed better, so the system would be cleaner. But the version in the repo is often outdated. So one should consider their preferences..

Comment: Fedora seems to update their repos quite quickly, but I can't speak to others, so point well-taken.

Comment: Just checked on my system (Fedora :) )..The repo has version v1.8.2, pip has v1.9.2. Well, not critical at all, unless there are some bugs..

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.0, do I do this in terminal or as a python program? Thanks :)

Comment: In ubuntu it should be something like `apt-get install python-numpy` or similar. I don't have ubuntu box accessible.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, doing `sudo apt-get install python-numpy`, and it installed something, which I presume that it worked (in installing `python-numpy`). However , it still says `ImportError: No module named 'numpy'` when I try running it with the code above, and says invalid syntax when I try importing with `import python-numpy`. :(

Comment: So you should look in the repository, it might have some package specific to python 3.4 (like python3-numpy, you can try it).

Comment: I did that... well something changed, the error I was was different this time (after installing `python3-numpy` in terminal). It looked like this: `Mon Mar 16 21:59:19 2015
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yichen/Desktop/python/numpy test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs`
 ... some more stuff... 
    `from . import multiarray
SystemError: initialization of multiarray raised unreported exception`

Comment: It's a different stuff. Maybe a subject for another question.